# Что за метка [смоленск]?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки

Что это за странная метка [смоленск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba)? Предлагаю удалить её по следующим причинам:

1. Непонятен её смысл;
2. С ней всего два вопроса ([первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1330965) и [второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493200));

Comment: Я убрал эту метку со второго вопроса. Скоро она самоудалится.

Comment: В данном случае это было отображение версии астралинукс. Кроме смоленска еще был орел

Comment: Наглядный пример, что надо оставить метки в покое и не трогать. Если вы не знаете смысл меток, не значит, что она бесполезная. А докапываться до 246234625 меток и пилить темы на мете - только засорять ресурс. Походит на замусоривание (как правильно заметил 
@yolosora 
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12713#comment55226_12713)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этому посту уже почти полгода, тогда я ещё не особено разбирался в удалении меткок. Сейчас бы я либо сам бы убрал метку с 2 вопросов, либо  оставил бы всё как есть, либо бы спросил в чате (с меткой всего-то 2 вопроса, если больше, то всё-таки создал бы пост на мете).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В [первом случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1330965/176217) меткой [смоленск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba) была указана [разновидность ОС "Astra Linux"](https://astralinux.ru/products/astra-linux-special-edition-1-6/). Т.е. сборка под x86-64. Обозначены и другие версии под другие платформы: Новороссийск, Севастополь, Ленинград.

> [image: версии Astra Linux]

Острой необходимости упоминать конкретную платформу в вопросе, как мне кажется, не было. Хотя это косвенно указывает используемую архитектуру и может потенциально влиять на ответ. Если версия реально важна, то метка, скорее всего должна была бы выглядеть как [astra-linux-смоленск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astra-linux-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba). В таком случае это не вызвало бы вопросов о смысле метки и это согласуется с номерными версиями продуктов, например, [visual-studio-2022](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2022).

[Второй вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1493200/176217), скорее всего, был помечен этой меткой просто по ошибке. Ну или автор, действительно, живёт в Смоленске и ожидал, что таким образом ему может ответить кто-то из его земляков.

Comment: @Зонтик к сожалению, это не так. Иначе все метки без описания можно было бы грохнуть. Или вообще запретить их существование.